# Ошибка. remove удаляет не элемент, а родителя

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Всем привет! Хочу удалить div с надписью корзина, но удаляется почему-то родительcкий div foot-carousel

```js
$("#foot-carousel:has('div'):contains('Корзина пуста.')").remove();
```

```html
<div id="foot-carousel" class="owl-carousel">
  <div>Корзина пуста.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Что выбрали в селекторе, то и удалилось. Вешайте id на вложенный div и его удаляйте

Comment: @carapuz, а без создания id никак? просто div подгружаются динамически и не очень понятно, да и не хочется всем присваивать id и еще это отслеживать. одной  строкой ведь можно как-то это сделать?

Comment: можно без id. Смотрите .children() в jQuery

Answer (score 3):

Так зачем тогда использушь `has`?

```
$("#foot-carousel:has('div'):contains('Корзина пуста.')").remove();
   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^|         ||                         |
   этот элемент  |         ||                         |
если внутри есть ^^^^^-----^|                         |
                       div  |                         |
и внутри есть текст         ^^^^^^^^^^----------------^
                                       Корзина пуста.
```

Надо так:

```
$("#foot-carousel div:contains('Корзина пуста.')").remove();
```

Comment: да, отлично, только теперь бы еще проверочку придумать, чтобы на первый раз срабатывало, ато удаляет только со второго раза

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#foot-carousel:has('div'):contains('Корзина пуста.')").children().remove();
```